# How to select only those rows where one column can have null or not null values for the same id

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Can someone please help me on how to select only the rows which has not null value of a column where that column can have null or not null values for the same id

I have a table like this

[image]

I need an output like this

[image]

Comment: _same id_, does that mean same `col1` value?

Comment: You mean if there is a record with no null value it is picked but if only ull then null one is also ok?

Comment: Should also col2 and col3 nulls be considered?

Comment: @Whencesoever yes if null and value both are there then value one should be picked , if only null one is there then null one should be picked

Comment: @jarlh yes same col1,col2,col3 values but only col4 differs with having null or not null

Comment: What are the data types of the *other* columns (not `col1`)? Are they all the same? Posting your data in a consumable format (*not* images) will greatly help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your description is not very clear. If I do understand correctly your requirement, you want only 1 row per `col1`. Choose the row with most not null value ?

```
select *
from
(
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by col1
                                      order by case when col2 is not null then 1 else 0 end
                                      +        case when col3 is not null then 1 else 0 end
                                      +        case when col4 is not null then 1 else 0 end 
                                      desc)
    from   a_table
) d
where rn = 1
```